# Dict from list python

Tags: python

I have this list :

```
>>> lst2 =['abc', '123']
```

If I try to create a dict from it,an error is returned

```
    >>> dict1 = dict(lst2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Goal :

> Create a dictionary from a list.

Expected result:

> `{'abc': '123'}`

Comment: Which dict would you like? `{'abc': '123'}`, i.e. the list is `[key1, value1, key2, value2, …]`?

Comment: Modify it as a tuple in a list. It's trying to parse "abc" into key pair which has length 3. For example `dict([('abc', '123')])`

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst2 = ['abc', '123', 'def','456', 'ghi', '789'] 
res_dct = {lst2[i]: lst2[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst2), 2)} 
print(res_dct)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need keys and values for a dict. Assuming that you want to treat your list as having `[key1, value1, key2, value2, ...]`, you can do the following:

```
keys = lst[::2]
values = lst[1::2]

dct = dict(zip(keys, values))
```